SwiftUIの画面固定のプログラムで@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor修飾子のプロパティappDelegateを定義すると反映されるのはなぜか
【環境】Swift5/Xcode16.1
画面の縦横を固定する方法について調べて，SwiftUIの学習をしていたのですが，次の構造体内のプロパティappDelegateがよくわかりませんでした．特に，なぜこれを宣言するだけでAppDelegateの処理が反映されるのかがわかりません．
より具体的な質問としては以下のとおりです．

勝手にappDelegateというプロパティを宣言しているように見えるが，これはAppプロトコルのデフォルト実装によって定義されているプロパティなのか？
上記１の項目でAppプロトコルのデフォルト実装によって定義されているとした場合，オプショナルでないのはなぜか？
プロパティappDelegateのapplicationメソッドがSampleApp構造体のどこかで実行されているという理解で良いか？

以下，記載したコードになります．
SampleApp.swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit


class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        // 横向き（Landscape）に固定
        return .landscape
    }
}


@main
struct SampleApp: App {
    // AppDelegateをSwiftUIに統合
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

ContentView.swift
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("Next") {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Hello Navigation Link")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .padding()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("Sub Screen")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Home Screen")
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

目的としては特定のViewのみ横固定縦固定を実現することでしたが，その前でつまづいてしまい，このような質問をいたしました．
